# python can't find already installed Module

Tags: python, python-2.7, mesh

Guys!
I'm using python 2.7 in windows by personal Reason.
Then I wanna use 'pymesh' library for some works.
but although the 'pymesh' module is already installed by using

```
python setup.py install
```

, the python show me this error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymesh-0.1-py2.7.egg\pymesh__init__.py", line 18, in
>
> from .Mesh import Mesh
>
> File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymesh-0.1-py2.7.egg\pymesh\Mesh.py", line 5, in
>
> import PyMesh
>
> ImportError: No module named PyMesh

and because I thought that the reason of this error is I didn't build 'pymesh', I entered this code in CMD

```
python setup.py build
```

but the prompt also show me error message

> running build
>
> Overriding default build process
>
> error: [Error 2]

so ... in this case , how can i fix this simple problem

Comment: and if you can ... let me know how to change line in script

Comment: Have you checked the [issue tracker](https://github.com/qnzhou/PyMesh/issues/27)?

Comment: @NilsWerner thank you for your comment , but I can't find any solution about this problem ... :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess you probably have to mention the pip version you are trying to install with, this happens if you have multiple versions of python/pip installed so if you are using python2.7 then use pip2.

```
pip2 install pymesh
```

then try importing it!

```
import pymesh
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i'm using anaconda. In anaconda prompt default pip is python 2.7 and pip2 not works ... sorry

Comment: (E:\ProgramData\Anaconda2) C:\Users\Lucid Jeong\Downloads\PyMesh-master>pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from E:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. I will post the procedure I adopted. I use **Debian 9.13**.
I believe it will works for debian likes. I also apologize for my google translator english

#### I did the following steps to install PyMesh

**Optional** - Set the python version as the system default. I chose to do it because I have other versions of python on my system.
`# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1

**1. Installing dependencies**
*Here I used administrator permission for installation via apt-get.*

`# apt install libeigen3-dev libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libmpfr-dev libboost-dev libboost-thread-dev libtbb-dev python3-dev curl git -y`

***Pip installation***

`# curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py`

**2. clone, part of third parties and requirements**
*As a common user of the system.*

`$  git clone https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh.git`

`$ cd PyMesh`

`$ git submodule update --init`

`` $ export PYMESH_PATH=`pwd` ``

`$ pip install -r $PYMESH_PATH/python/requirements.txt`

**3. Install CMAKE**

*When getting errors in the build step, I noticed that the messages pointed to my outdated version of CMAKE. I upgraded **(version 3.13.4)** using the Debian Buster repository. You may prefer to build from sources. I chose to use apt-get.*

`# echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster.list`

`# apt update && apt install cmake -y`

**4. Build and install**

*Still in the PyMesh directory, with a common user.*

`$ ./setup.py build`

`$ ./setup.py install  --user`

**5. Test**

`$ python -c "import pymesh; pymesh.test()"`

reference links

https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-default-python-version-on-debian-9-stretch-linux
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/